# how to get responsive layout for embedded videos/elements/images etc in html/css?

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to have 3 youtube videos embedded on my website in line.
I already have this and it works. However it is not completely responsive yet (on mobile devices etc)

```
<div style="”display: inline-block; float: left; width: 100%; max-width: 350px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L_jWHffIx5E" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

    <div style="”display: inline; float: right; width: 100%; max-width: 350px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mYBSayCsH0" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

    <div style="”display: inline; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%; max-width: 350px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/emGri7i8Y2Y" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>



    <div style="”display: inline-block; clear: both; height: 1em;"></div>
```

Now when the screen is getting smaller the second video overlays the first one. The 3th video seems to work well and jumps to the next line on smaller screens.

It has to do something with auto margins.
Note I have css in the html line for convenience now.

Can someone help me? Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/ this might help to your requirement

Comment: http://embedresponsively.com/ this might help

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS and if need change css selector names

**CSS:**
.

```
hs-responsive-embed { 
position: relative; 
height: 0; 
overflow: hidden; 
padding-top: 0; 
padding-left: 0; 
padding-right: 0; 
}

.hs-responsive-embed iframe, 
.hs-responsive-embed object, 
.hs-responsive-embed embed { 
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
border: 0; 
}

.hs-responsive-embed, 
.hs-responsive-embed.hs-responsive-embed-youtube, 
.hs-responsive-embed.hs-responsive-embed-wistia, 
.hs-responsive-embed.hs-responsive-embed-vimeo { 
padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. I will check it:)

Answer (score 0):

I will advise you to use media queries to make your page more responsive.
Media queries are used in css  to specify the what the page will look like at certain widths or heights.If your not yet into css, I'll advise you to google codecademy and take their "Learn responsive design course, that will help you.The course is free so no worries about financial expenses.
But for now I'll give you a few tips on how to do it. Instead of using the regular width and height attributes of the iframe use css to do this
and you will be able to easily change their width and height in response to the page size.For example,
each of your divs will have this style in your css file

```
div{
display:inline-block;
float: left; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 350px;
}

iframe{
width:560;
height:315;
}
```

The css code above will serve as the regular design for you page. Now, the mobile phone design for your page can be determined by this css code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){

}
```

In the  media query your can now redesign your page to be mobile responsive. This will not change your first css design by default.It will only affect your design when the screen of your device is 320px or below.

Comment: Thanks for your input and for taking the time to response:) I will check it

Answer (score 0):

What about keep it simple, using [css calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)?

```css
iframe {width:100%;height:calc}
```

```html
<div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L_jWHffIx5E" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe></div>

<div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mYBSayCsH0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe></div>

<div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/emGri7i8Y2Y" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe></div>
```

[image]

Or all aside in the same row:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%
}
```

```html
<div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L_jWHffIx5E" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mYBSayCsH0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/emGri7i8Y2Y" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe>
</div>
```

[image]

On the same rrow with no over lapse.

```css
iframe{width:33%; min-width:240px; display:inline-block}
```

```html
<div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L_jWHffIx5E" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0mYBSayCsH0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/emGri7i8Y2Y" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" frameborder="0" width="560"></iframe>
</div>
```

[image]

Check out this good reading: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/future-of-web-design/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks a bit cleaner. However I don't want to overlap videos over each other. I want them in a specific width (eg 320px), times 3 videos (with even padding between them) and when smaller stack them under each other. The width can then all change automatically (eg using 100%, if smaler then 320px). I will give your link a read, thanks:)

Comment: Come on, this is easy, open the debugger «Inspect element» and play around! Updated to match your query.